# Python cannot import 'Token' from 'token'

Tags: python, import

I'm trying to make a lexer in python but when I try to import a class from file token.py I get this error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Token' from 'token'
```

the code for token.py is as follows

```
from enum import Enum


class Token():
    def __init__(self, ttype, value=None):
        self.type = ttype
        self.value = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return {'type':self.type, 'value':self.value}
    


class TokenType(Enum):
    NUMBER = 0
    PLUS = 1
    MINUS = 2
    MULTIPLY = 3
    DIVIDE = 4
    LPAREN = 5
    RPAREN = 6
```

and the import statement is

```
from token import Token, TokenType
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a library in python called token, so your interpreter might be confusing it with the inbuilt python library.
Try to rename the library.
Name it `token_2.py` or something

Answer (score 0):

don't forget to save all files with dependencies in your code before launching the application. My code working after saving all files.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/76984829/11107541